# Wrapping any node.js callback automatically

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node.js, callback, socket.io

Is it possible to write code that wrap any node.js i/o-callback with my own function?
(When I say i/o-callback function I mean function that get invoked after some i/o action)

Why do I need such a thing? example: I have a socket.io server
I have bunch of global functions that I am actually getting as an input (I can't change it, not even reading it, I just paste it as is in my code)

the callback of socket.io.connect(socket,...callback ) interact with those global functions. now upon new connection we set access to the current socket in a global level. 
the programmers who wrote those global function are aware of the currentSocket variable and uses it..

The problem is that after calling some async i/o function, some other user/socket might connect and change the currentSocket, later when the async i/o function will get executed the currentSocket will be equals to a different user/socket rather than the original user/socket that invoked that async-function

I thought maybe I can somehow auto-wrap the i/o callback and closure the currentSocket variable, yet I am not sure how to do that...
any idea?

```
var currentSocket = undefined;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  currentSocket = socket;
  socket.on('msg', function (data) {
    global[data.functionToInvoke];
  });
});

//global function that I can't change or even analyze/read
//========================================================
function g1(){
   //might use currentSocket
   //might invoke async stuff like
   fs.readfile(...cb)
}
function g2(){
   //might use currentSocket
   //might invoke async stuff like
   redisClient.get(...cb)
}
```

Comment: im confused, when you define the callback you are defining your own function...what do you mean by 'wrap'?

Comment: @hvgotcodes he probably means intersect dynamically without doing it on everything. @MrOhad No, but you can intersect _all_ functions.

Comment: well, let's assume that someone else wrote the callback...

Comment: @Raynos can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MrOhad [node-proxy](https://github.com/viirya/node-proxy)

Comment: @Raynos thanks, but what about just catching the callbacks? any idea how can I write such an add-on? thanks again!

Comment: @MrOhad A callback is just a function. You can magically wrap functions. What makes callbacks special from other functions? If they are not special / unique then you can't distinquish between a callback and a function

Comment: @Raynos I want to catch the event when node.js is done executing some code, registering a function(callback) and go back to the even-loop... do I miss something?

Comment: I added a meaningful example to the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions all share the `currentSocket` global variable (and if you can't change them), it is not possible to have multiple connections (as long as the functions are async). If you could change them it would be best just to pass the socket as first parameter to your functions. Another way is to move the definition of `currentSocket` and your functions inside of the `io.sockets connection` callback. In this case the `currentSocket` variable forms a closure and everything should work as expected:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var currentSocket = socket;
  socket.on('msg', function (data) {
    global[data.functionToInvoke];
  });

  //global function that I can't change or even analyze/read
  //========================================================
  function g1(){
     //might use currentSocket
     //might invoke async stuff like
     fs.readfile(...cb)
  }
  function g2(){
     //might use currentSocket
     //might invoke async stuff like
     redisClient.get(...cb)
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly one way to accomplish it could be via alias method chain. You can pass the original callback into anonymous function expression which returns new function expression:

```
cb = (function (original) {
  return function () {
    // do something with original callback
    original();
    // add more functionality 
  }
})(cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap an established method in JS the way to do it is by renaming & replacing.

e.g.

```
 Array.prototype._toString = Array.prototype.toString;
 Array.prototype.toString = function(){ return "wrapped["+this._toString()+"]"; };
 console.log(["1","2","3"].toString());
```

I'd suggest applying that to your use case, in this case either the io.sockets object, or a deeper object, perhaps all the way down on the EventEmitter.emit() method.